# Fetching data in the loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

So I'm trying to connect to external server called Pexels to get some photos. I'm doing that from node.js but it is just a javascript issue. Pexels unfortunately lets user to download object with only 40 pictures per page.

```
https://api.pexels.com/v1/curated?per_page=40&page=1 // 40 is maximum
```

But actually I need more then that. I'd like to get 160 results, ie. to combine all first four pages. In order to do that I tried looping the request:

```
    let pexelsData = [];
    for(let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
      const randomPage = getRandomFromRange(1, 100); //pages should be randomized
      const moreData = await axios.get(`https://api.pexels.com/v1/curated?per_page=40&page=${randomPage}`,
        createHeaders('bearer ', keys.pexelsKey));

      pexelsData = [ ...moreData.data.photos, ...pexelsData ];
    }
```

Now I can use pexelsData but it work very unstable, sometimes it is able to get all combined data, sometimes it crashes. Is there a correct and stable way of looping requests?

Comment: It doesn't crash because of code and there is no JavaScript/Node magic will make it not crash -- you might be exceeding the API's limit here.

Comment: So am I just unable to dowload this in stable way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You work with 3rd party API, which has rate limits. So you should add rate limits to your code. The simplest solution for you is using `p-limit` or similar approach form [promise-fun](https://github.com/sindresorhus/promise-fun)

It will looks like that:

```
const pLimit = require('p-limit');

const limit = pLimit(1);

const input = [
  limit(() => fetchSomething('foo')),
  limit(() => fetchSomething('bar')),
  limit(() => doSomething())
];

(async () => {
  // Only one promise is run at once
  const result = await Promise.all(input);
  console.log(result);
})();
```

Comment: Can I use it in my loop scenario?

Comment: Create at the loop array of promises with limit, then use `Promise.all`

Answer (score 1):

you can break it into functions like..

```
let images=[];
const getResponse = async i=> {
    if(i<5)
    return await axios.get(`https://api.pexels.com/v1/curated?per_page=40&page=${i}`)
}

const getImage = (i)=>{
if(i<5){
    try {
        const request = getResponse(i);
        images = [...images,...request];
        //  here you will get all the images in an array
        console.log(images)
        getImage(++i)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("catch error",error)
    //   getImage(i)    
    }
}


}

getImage(0);  //call initail
```

Comment: I guess it won't work because you cannot do const request = getResponse(i) because getResponse(i) will provide a promise.

Comment: you can use async await for this function also.. const request = await getResponse(i);